# Chrome and Firefox not working/slow

Tags: upgrade, firefox, google-chrome, chromium, ethernet

Chrome has stopped working and Firefox is slow, sometimes so slow that it  does not work at all. I have tried installing Chromium, but the effects were the same. I uninstalled Chrome and then updated Ubuntu to 13.10, but this had no effect either. The computer dual-boots with Windows 7, so I have tried Chrome and Firefox on Windows and they work fine. My computer has 6GB of RAM and high speed internet with a wired connection.
Thanks Brian

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find solution for [Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/a/474529/624697)

For fixing Chrome do the following:

1. Set IPv6 DNS servers - [Public Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using) - 2001:4860:4860::8888 and 2001:4860:4860::8844
2. In Chrome open chrome://net-intenals/dns#dns and click button "Clear host cache".