# Google Chrome and Firefox very slow

Tags: gnome, firefox, google-chrome, internet

I have a problem since I moved on Gnome3.Google Chrome and Firefox runs slow on some sites,sometimes it won't load the page or page crashes!
I have this problem only on Gnome3 and I don't want to change it! What can I do?

Comment: Oh and Youtube and Facebook works with no lag!

Comment: My guess is that your computer is running out of RAM and/or processor cycles. My advice (if you're unwilling to switch desktop environments) would be to install the **uBlock Origin** addon for firefox and chrome, which will block a lot of unnecessary ads and javascript that can slow down web browsing.

Comment: Is not that.When I use Chrome I use only 2.2 GB of 3.7 and 20% cpu usage!And I have steam opened too!

Comment: Ok -- I wasn't sure, since you didn't list any of your computer's specs. Some people only have 2GB of ram :)

Comment: I have a Toshiba Satellite C850-1G3: CPU: Intel Celeron 1000m 1.8ghz ,4GB ram 1600Mhz, HD Graphics 2500

Comment: I have a 6th-gen i5 with 20GB of ram -- ubuntu 16.04 // it still uses a ton of CPU. I don't get it.

Comment: I've faced the very same problem and I've been able to solve it at least for Firefox, using [this answer from another Ask Ubuntu question.](http://askubuntu.com/a/474529/624697)